# Link Database in DatagridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

i am working on a inventory system and i design a form for inventory statue that shows items from database to a datagridview.

```
     mycon.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select ItemName, LowStock, Quantity from Pharmacy_Items";, mycon);
     SqlDataAdapter ada2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
     DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

     ada2.Fill(dt2);
     datagridview.DataSource = dt2;
     mycon.Close();
```

now i want to add another column beside the quantity  that shows items status like if items quantities are low than lowStock or equal to lowStock then in status column should be "Low" and if the item quantity is more than lowStock quantity it should write "Ok".
and items which have "Low" status should change its row color to red. so we can know which item is in low status and we have to order for inventory.

I Tried this:

```
for (i =0; i < datagridview.Row.Count; i++)
{
  if( datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value >= datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
  {
   datagridview.Columns.Add("Low");
  }
   else
  {
   datagridview.Columns.Add("Ok");
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you are adding multiple columns with this above code. So you might end up with multiple columns with headings OK, Low.  Maybe you should consider creating a SQL view which contains all the necessary information you need to display, and then just bind your Datagrid, which will automatically add all the columns included in your SELECT query

Comment: like How i can make SQL view which contains all the necessary info. : )

Comment: Show me your table "Pharmacy_Items" and I will be able to help you. Otherwise, check out this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: Thank you for your precious reply : ) My Pharmacy_Items has ItemCode, ItemName, LowStock, Quantity and Price Field.

Comment: @ Kho Dam, we hope that your issue has been resolved. May I suggest some further reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work... regards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
                mycon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select ItemName, LowStock, Quantity, CASE when Quantity < LowStock then 'LOW' else 'OK' end as [Status]  from Pharmacy_Items", mycon);
                SqlDataAdapter ada2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

                ada2.Fill(dt2);
                dataGridView.DataSource = dt2;
                mycon.Close();
```

And to change row color use the CellFormatting event like so...

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Status"].Value.ToString() == "LOW")
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```